# How to set Publish Date in Word Document using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a situation where a user can upload a word document which contains placeholders for certain properties (i.e. in MS Word the user has gone to Insert > Quick Parts > Document Properties and chosen a property). The specific properties I want to support are `Title`, `Author`, `Company` and `Publish Date`.

`Title` and `Author` are set as Package Properties, and `Company` is set as an Extended File Property. These are set with the below code, which works correctly:

```
private static void SetDocumentProperties(ReportTemplateModel model, WordprocessingDocument wordDocument)
{
    //these properties always exist
    wordDocument.PackageProperties.Title = model.Title;
    wordDocument.PackageProperties.Creator = model.Author;
    wordDocument.PackageProperties.Created = DateTime.Now;
    wordDocument.PackageProperties.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    //these properties can be null
    if (wordDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart == null)
    {
        wordDocument.AddNewPart<ExtendedFilePropertiesPart>();
    }
    if (wordDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties == null)
    {
        wordDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties = new Properties(new Company(model.SiteName));
    }
    else
    {
        wordDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Company = new Company(model.SiteName);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't work out how the set the `Publish Date` property. I have tried adding it as a Custom File Property using the below code (which is adapted from https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/292005/WDSetCustomProperty), but this does not work. I've read a few things about setting custom properties, but I'm confused how they're meant to work. I'm also unsure if the `Publish Date` should actually be set as a custom property, or some other type of property.

```
var customProps = wordDocument.CustomFilePropertiesPart;
if (customProps == null)
{
    customProps = wordDocument.AddCustomFilePropertiesPart();
    customProps.Properties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.Properties();
}
var properties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.Properties();

//I have tried both of these lines, neither worked.
//properties1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("op", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties");
properties1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("vt", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes");

var customDocumentProperty1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.CustomDocumentProperty()
{
    FormatId = "{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}",
    PropertyId = 2,
    Name = "Publish Date"
};

customDocumentProperty1.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.VariantTypes.VTLPWSTR { Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() });

properties1.Append(customDocumentProperty1);

part.Properties = properties1;
```

What type of property should the `Publish Date` be set as, and what is the right syntax for setting this?

**Update:** I have found that `Publish Date` is a `CoverPageProperty` which can be created using the below snippet, but I still haven't found how to set it correctly within the document.

```
var coverPageProps = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.CoverPageProps.CoverPageProperties
{
    PublishDate = new PublishDate(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below code to my SetDocumentProperties method seems to work. I must admit I don't fully understand the below code, so any explanation would still be welcome. Additionally, if anyone has a solution which doesn't include writing XML as a string inside C# I would much prefer to avoid that.

```
const string publishDatePartId = "publishDatePart";

var publishDateXmlPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<CustomXmlPart>("application/xml", publishDatePartId);

var writer = new XmlTextWriter(publishDateXmlPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

writer.WriteRaw($"<CoverPageProperties xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps\">" +
                $"<PublishDate>{DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()}</PublishDate>" +
                $"</CoverPageProperties>");

writer.Flush();

writer.Close();

var customXmlPropertiesPart = publishDateXmlPart.AddNewPart<CustomXmlPropertiesPart>(publishDatePartId);

customXmlPropertiesPart.DataStoreItem = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomXmlDataProperties.DataStoreItem()
{
    //I don't know what this ID is, but it seems to somehow relate to the Publish Date
    ItemId = "{55AF091B-3C7A-41E3-B477-F2FDAA23CFDA}"
};
```